# SQL Join - Limit to base table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, hive

I have 4 tables that I want to link together based on the information in the sales_details table which will serve as the base table (limiting results based on the sales_details table)

1)I want to pull all columns from the sales_detail table that are mastercard orders but since the sales_detail table doesn't have a column to identity the type of transaction it is, I have to:

- link the sales_detail table to the sales_total table by transaction_ID to get the pay_id
- use the pay_id from the sales_total table and link to payment type table in order to filter for payment type
- link product_id from sales_detail table to product_detail table to get product name

```
BASE TABLE : sales_detail 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_id|   product_cost |  product_id  |    country
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      20       |      87956666 |    usa
|   10/1     |   12345         |      50       |      63333333 |    usa
|   10/5     |  82456          |      50       |      63333333 |    usa
|   10/9     |  64789          |      30       |      45665466 |    canada
|   10/12    |  08546          |      19       |      78979879 |    usa
|   10/15    |  87988          |      19       |      78979879 |    usa
|   10/17    |  65898         |       50       |      63333333 |    canada
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

```
table : payment_type
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   pay_id | pay_type|   payment  |  phone_number
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   08585  |   24    | mastercard   |214-444-1234    |
|   07895  |   35    | visa         |555-111-1234    |
|   08585  |   24    | mastercard   |214-444-1234    |
|   08657  |   35    | visa         |817-333-1234    |
|   02345  |   24    |  mastercard  |214-555-1234    |
|   02245  |   35   |  visa         |888-555-1234    |
|   08785  |   24   |  mastercard   |240-555-1234    |
|   06587  |   24   |  mastercard   |240-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

```
table : sales_total
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   pay_id | transaction_id|   unit sold |  
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   08585  |   12345      |      2       |
|   07895  |   82456      |      1       |
|   08657  |   64789      |      1       |
|   04568  |   32145      |      3       |   
|   02345  |   08546      |      1       |
|   08785  |   87988      |      1       |
|   06587  |   65898      |      1       | 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

```
table : product_detail
+-------+-----------+-----------+--+
|   product_name    |  product id
+-------+-----------+-----------+--+
      popcorn      |      87956666
      cheetos      |      63333333
      soda         |      93333333
      milk         |      45665466
|     water        |      78979879
+-------+-----------+-----------+--+
```

**I want the output to look something like this: **

```
IDEAL OUTPUT
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_id|   product_cost |  product_id    |   product |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      20       |      87956666   |   popcorn |
|   10/1     |   12345         |      50       |      63333333   |   cheetos |
|   10/12    |   08546         |      19       |      78979879   |   water   |
|   10/15    |  87988          |      19       |      93333333   |   soda    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

**im trying to get all orders from the sales_detail table that have paid by mastercard and from the usa. I tried using left joins and not only it takes forever because of the large tables (doesnt even load) and it also gives me duplicates. What am i doing wrong?**

This is the code i used but failed as it took over 20+hrs and timed out:

```
select t1.order_date, 
t1.transaction_id,
t1.product_cost,
t1.product_id
t4.product_name
from sales_detail t1
left join sales_total t2 on t1.transaction_id=t2.transaction_id
left join payment_type t3 on t2.pay_id=t3.pay_id
left join product_detail t4 on t1.product_id=t4.product_id
where t1.order_date between '2020-10-1' and'2020-12-30'
and t1.country not in ('canada')
and t3.pay_type= 24;
```

there is no output for this code as after 20hrs it could never finish :(

Thanks in advance! I am a beginner so still learning the ins and outs of sql! (am using hive)

Comment: "This is the code i used but failed:"  what do you mean ? ... you have an error ?? show the exact error message ..  wrong result .. update ypur question and add your actual result  too.

Comment: can you do a inner join on t2 and t3 instead of a left join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing seems to be wrong with your query and the reason you failed could be due to huge data present in sales table I would presume.

How ever lets give it a try by considering few points, as You only need columns from t1 and t4 , I would go for exists rather joining the tables without taking any columns to the select clause and second point , we can do a inner join between t2 and t3 considering t2 will never have a record with value null in pay_id column

```
select t1.order_date,t1.transaction_id,t1.product_cost,t1.product_id,t4.product_name 
from sales_detail t1  
left join product_detail t4 on t1.product_id = t4.product_id 
where t1.order_date between '2020-10-1' and'2020-12-30'
  and t1.country not in ('canada')
  and exists (select 1 
                from sales_total t2 
               join payment_type t3 on t2.pay_id = t3.pay_id
              where t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
                and t3.pay_type= 24);
```

If you still face performance issue try creating index on "transaction_id" and "product_id ".

I hope this help you taking a step forward. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! I think this works since I just tried it on SQL fiddler, but how do you index "transaction_id" and "product_id"?

Comment: What I mean is if the query is still slow you should consider creating index. Create index idx_produxt_id on product_detail(product_id) and again if required on transaction_id based on data in t1 or t4. See why we need index here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg06idx.htm

Comment: That makes sense, didn't know index existed. I read a lot about indexes, but my question is should I create that index in a separate command or can I keep it in this table and rewrite the left join statement as:   left join product_detail t4 on t1.product_id = t4. idx_produxt_id?

Comment: Yes, it's DDL(data definition language) command like create table, so you have to create it separately but then it belongs to the table on which you created. After that to use the index with latest statistics you have to gather the statistics (optional) on the table using dbms_gather_statistics(Oracle db) and finally(I missed to mention earlier) the query should remain unchanged, however if you don't expect product_id column to be null in t1 you can go for inner join instead left join.

Answer (score -1):

Missing comma after t1.product_id.
Use country = 'usa' as the country filter instead of not in.
Check the date range.2020-10-1 is Oct of 2020 which is in future.

```
select 
     t1.order_date,  
     t1.transaction_id, 
     t1.product_cost, 
     t1.product_id,
     t4.product_name 
from sales_detail t1
join product_detail t4 on t1.product_id=t4.product_id 
join sales_total t2 on t1.transaction_id=t2.transaction_id 
join payment_type t3 on t2.pay_id=t3.pay_id  
where t1.order_date between ('2020-12-30' and '2020-1-10') and 
      t1.country = 'usa' and 
      t3.pay_type= 24;
```

Comment: how do you get t3.pay_type if you dont get sales_table?

Comment: But i think i do need the sales_total table because it has pay_id which will link the sales_detail table to the payment_type table. I think this query will also produce duplicates though...

Comment: Select 2 between 3 and 1